# video meta data extractor

Tags: metadata, extract

I need a **cross platform- metadata extractor** to retrieve the title , author , singers etc., (properties) from a video .

TagLib requires a cmake build . Exiv2 also needs a build. I need something that need not be built once in every platform , my application is deployed. Something that is readily usable.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost any multimedia player allow you to read video and audio metadata.

If you really want a suggestion (even if it then risk to become a [shopping question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394)) you should try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

With it you can view and copy metadata from (almost) any audio and video file format.